# redis not working in my python django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis

I first followed the tutorial on the heroku site. I did this

```
pip install rq
```

then in a worker.py file

```
import os

    import redis
    from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

    listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

    redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

    conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Connection(conn):
            worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
            worker.work()
```

and then

```
python worker.py
```

and I got the following error

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
        sock = self._connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
        raise err
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
        sock.connect(socket_address)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 572, in execute_command
        connection.send_command(*args)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
        self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
        self.connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
        raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
    redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
        sock = self._connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
        raise err
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
        sock.connect(socket_address)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "worker.py", line 15, in <module>
        worker.work()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 423, in work
        self.register_birth()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 242, in register_birth
        if self.connection.exists(self.key) and \
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 855, in exists
        return self.execute_command('EXISTS', name)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 578, in execute_command
        connection.send_command(*args)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
        self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
        self.connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
        raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
    redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

I then went to google and found the package index which I also followed which is

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.set('foo', 'bar')
```

hit enter and got the following message

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
        sock = self._connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
        raise err
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
        sock.connect(socket_address)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 572, in execute_command
        connection.send_command(*args)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
        self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
        self.connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
        raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
    redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
        sock = self._connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
        raise err
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
        sock.connect(socket_address)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1072, in set
        return self.execute_command('SET', *pieces)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 578, in execute_command
        connection.send_command(*args)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
        self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
        self.connect()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
        raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
    redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

I have done no more or less then what these tutorials ask. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the redis server. Type redis-server on you console to start the server(Mac OSX).

```
$redis-server
```

Remember that the worker needs a broker(redis) in order to communicate with your app.

Comment: when I do I get this message bash: redis-server: command not found. Am I to install it locally or globally? because I'm doing this from within my virtualenv. and in the docs I'm reading it doesn't specify.

Comment: @losee u should install it globally, redis is not a python package or app. The command to start the server depends on your OS.

Comment: brew installed it, hit redis-server and it worked. Step one.